# result = "Error 25: Expected: ). Line: 1 -> $._ext_Illustrator.embedPDF(‪D:/IllustratorTest/test.pdf)

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to Import a pdf file as a group item in adobe illustrator using extendscript. I'm adding the code snippet below for importing

```
embedPDF:function(dest){
var embedDoc = new File(dest);
if ( app.documents.length > 0 && embedDoc.exists )
{
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var placed = doc.groupItems.createFromFile( embedDoc );
    return "true";
}}
```

I'm getting the below error

result = "Error 25: Expected: ).
Line: 1
-> $._ext_Illustrator.embedPDF(‪D:/IllustratorTest/test.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You have a JavaScript typo.
The function should have a name, and then you need to invoke this function.

Probably you copied this code from another source, and the code was inside an object.

Change your code to this (remember to change last line to your actual file path):

```
function embedPDF(dest) {
    var embedDoc = new File(dest);
    if (app.documents.length > 0 && embedDoc.exists) {
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
        var placed = doc.groupItems.createFromFile(embedDoc);
        return true;
    }
}
embedPDF('C:/path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf');
```

Comment: I'm using Adobe extend script and that is not like a proper javascript syntax. I can define a function like that

Comment: I'm pretty know what is ExtendScript. When you copy your code to the ESTK it's not running, so maybe you didn't copy here the entire code